# MS SQL Pivot Dynamic Headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have the following two tables:

```
Serial  Key     Value
ABC     Attr1   ABC1
ABC     Attr2   ABC2
ABC     Attr3   ABC3
XYZ     Attr1   XYZ1
XYZ     Attr2   XYZ2
XYZ     Attr3   XYZ3
```

and

```
Key     Include IncludeOrder
Attr1   Y       2
Attr2   NULL    NULL
Attr3   Y       1
```

The first table is the data, the second table is the data `Key`s to include on the report.

I want to generate the following from a query:

```
Serial  Attr3   Attr1
ABC     ABC3    ABC1
XYZ     XYZ3    XYZ1
```

I know this will require a pivot, with a `GROUP BY` on `Serial`, but I haven't been able to complete the subquery to pull the columns designated by `Include` or sort them to be ordered correctly in the output by `IncludeOrder`.

Comment: could you post this as text instead of images? Makes it a LOT easier for others to work with.

Comment: @SeanLange Done. Thanks!

Comment: see accepted answer from [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy to achieve with dynamic-SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'SELECT Serial, <cols> FROM t GROUP BY Serial;';

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG(CONCAT('MIN(CASE WHEN [key] = ''',
                      [key],
                       ''' THEN [value] END) AS ',
                       QUOTENAME([key])),
                       ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY IncludeOrder)
FROM r
WHERE Include = 'Y';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<cols>', @cols);

SELECT @sql;
EXEC(@sql);
```

Output query:

```
SELECT Serial,
       MIN(CASE WHEN [key] = 'Attr3' THEN [value] END) AS [Attr3],
       MIN(CASE WHEN [key] = 'Attr1' THEN [value] END) AS [Attr1] 
FROM t 
GROUP BY Serial;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4de05386b2db0aca8abf2965c869631c)**

---

Notes:

- SQL Server 2017 and above (because of `STRING_AGG`, feel free to rewrite it to [XML+STUFF version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string))
- conditional aggregation with `MIN`

Comment: Unfortunately I have to work with Server 2014... is there a similar way to achieve this? I've not worked with the XML path queries yet.

Comment: @Mooseman Time to learn new thing :) If you don't know how to follow use simple while loop to implement string concatenation. I will leave it for you as exercise :)